# How to I remove duplicate words when using =TEXTJOIN() function in google sheets or excel

Tags: excel, google-sheets, duplicates, textjoin

I am trying to find a function that I can use that will eliminate duplicate wording when i join two cells together. I will attach a picture to show you what my ideal return is.
[Ideal Return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKEBf.png)

For the Row 1&2 column, this is the function I used (=textjoin(":",True,A2,B2)) , but i would like to find a function that will return me the Ideal Return instead. I am not looking to use the find and replace feature, as I would like to document each step I made, so a function would be best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this one?

```
=IF(EQ(A2;B2);A2;TEXTJOIN(":";true;A2;B2))
```

nothing fancy though, if you want the fancy one, the answer with **flatten** from Harun24hr is better.

But it is easy in what it does, if the cells are the same, then take the first cell, otherwise, concat the results.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use `UNIQUE()` function to remove duplicates. Try-

```
=TEXTJOIN(":",1,UNIQUE(FLATTEN(A2:B2)))
```

For dynamic spill results use `BYROW()` function. Try-

```
=BYROW(A2:B4,LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN(":",1,UNIQUE(FLATTEN(x)))))
```

To make input range dynamic (instead of fixed rows) can use-

```
=BYROW(A2:INDEX(B2:B,COUNTA(A2:A)),LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN(":",1,UNIQUE(FLATTEN(x)))))
```

[image]